# Firebase authentication Interception

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am developing an App in flutter and firebase, which has a referral program included where by a user can refer another user and earn some point. The problem is I only want to give the point when the referred user verifies his/her email. 
How can i intercept user verification process in firebase. 
For example I want to give a referee a bonus when his/her downline verifies his email.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to get your code executed once a user's `email_verified` flag is toggled on the Firebase Authentication servers.

The closest you can get is to periodically run a process in a trusted environment (your development machine, a server you control, or Cloud Functions) that then uses the Firebase Admin SDK to [retrieve a list of all users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users), and checks whether their email address is verified by comparing it against a list you maintain of users who you've already given the bonus to.

Instead of running this periodically, you could also have the client-side application code calls into Cloud Functions when it detects that the user has verified their email address; something like `checkBonusEligibility`. The server then performs that same check as before, as otherwise users could abuse your system by calling the Cloud Function themselves.

Comment: I have tried to give your question accreditation, but i gt a response that a new member accreditation cant be counted, Thanks again

Comment: You indeed need a certain reputation in order to be able to vote (up or down). But since you asked this question, you can **accept** an answer.